# a uptime command in discord py, i get always the same error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

```
    @commands.command(aliases=['uptime', 'up'])
    async def status(self, ctx):

        timeUp = time.time() - self.bot.startTime
        hours = timeUp / 3600
        minutes = (timeUp / 60) % 60
        seconds = timeUp % 60

        admin = self.bot.AppInfo.owner
        users = 0
        channel = 0
        if len(self.bot.commands_used.items()):
            commandsChart = sorted(self.bot.commands_used.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=False)
            topCommand = commandsChart.pop()
            commandsInfo = '{} (Top-Command: {} x {})'.format(sum(self.bot.commands_used.values()), topCommand[1], topCommand[0])
        else:
            commandsInfo = str(sum(self.bot.commands_used.values()))
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            users += len(guild.members)
            channel += len(guild.channels)

        embed = discord.Embed(color=ctx.me.top_role.colour)
        embed.set_footer(text='UwU')
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.me.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name='Admin', value=admin, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Uptime', value='{0:.0f} Stunden, {1:.0f} Minuten und {2:.0f} Sekunden\n'.format(hours, minutes, seconds), inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Beobachtete Benutzer', value=users, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Beobachtete Channel', value=channel, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Ausgeführte Commands', value=commandsInfo, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Bot Version', value=self.bot.botVersion, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Discord.py Version', value=discord.__version__, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Python Version', value=platform.python_version(), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Betriebssystem', value=f'{platform.system()} {platform.release()} {platform.version()}', inline=False)
        await ctx.send('**:information_source:** Informationen über diesen Bot:', embed=embed)
```

I need help with this command

i get following error: `[10.02.2021 16:31:10][WARN] Unknown error:[0mCommand raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'startTime'`

i checked all my imports.. my imports are

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import json
import aiohttp
import random
import ast
from pymongo import MongoClient
from discord.utils import get
from pytz import timezone
import os
import math
import itertools
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound, MissingPermissions, MessageNotFound
import asyncio

Comment: `self.bot.startTime` replace with `start_time`

Comment: @Ajay now i get  Unknown error:[0mCommand raised an exception: NameError: name 'start_time' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`discord.ext.commands.Bot` does not save the date the bot started. However, you could do that manually very easily. Inside the `on_ready` function in the **main** file, create a bot variable and save the current datetime. Make sure you import it as well!

In case you didn't know, bot variables are declared like so; `bot.your_var_name = value`. Be careful, however, because you might overwrite something. In your case, you could try;

```py
import datetime

'''
Import everything else you need and
make sure to declare the bot client
'''

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Then you can use `bot.start_time` outside that file. For instance, in a cog it would be `self.bot.start_time`.

And in your code, I recommend using `datetime` instead of `time`, it's much easier to work with.